# Xamarin.iOS - Set audio sample rate for each video when merging multiple videos

Tags: c#, audio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, avfoundation

Trying to stitch multiple videos using AVAssetTrack and AVMutableCompositionTrack. Uploaded videos could have different audio settings (e.g. sample rate) - what's the best way to pass in desired audio settings when adding AVAssetTracks to AVMutableVideoComposition? Currently using the following code, certain videos with 48KHz stitched with 44.1KHz produce no sound when played on IE/Edge, but works on other browsers:

```
Composition = new AVMutableComposition();
AVMutableCompositionTrack VideoCompositionTrack = Composition.AddMutableTrack(AVMediaType.Video, 0);
AVMutableCompositionTrack AudioCompositionTrack = Composition.AddMutableTrack(AVMediaType.Audio, 1);
AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction LayerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction.FromAssetTrack(VideoCompositionTrack);

CMTime StartTime = CMTime.Zero;
AVUrlAssetOptions Options = new AVUrlAssetOptions
{
    PreferPreciseDurationAndTiming = true
};
CMTimeRange TimeRange;
NSError InsertError = null;
int Counter = 0;
CGSize FinalRenderSize = new CGSize();

foreach (NSUrl VideoLocation in SelectedVideoLocations)
{
    using (AVAsset Asset = new AVUrlAsset(VideoLocation, Options))
    {
        TimeRange = new CMTimeRange()
        {
            Start = CMTime.Zero,
            Duration = Asset.Duration
        };

        if (Asset.TracksWithMediaType(AVMediaType.Video).Length > 0)
        {
            using (AVAssetTrack VideoAssetTrack = Asset.TracksWithMediaType(AVMediaType.Video)[0])
            {
                if (Counter == 0)
                {
                    FinalRenderSize = VideoAssetTrack.NaturalSize;
                }

                LayerInstruction.SetTransform(VideoAssetTrack.PreferredTransform, StartTime);
                VideoCompositionTrack.InsertTimeRange(TimeRange, VideoAssetTrack, StartTime, out InsertError);
            }
        }

        if (Asset.TracksWithMediaType(AVMediaType.Audio).Length > 0)
        {
            using (AVAssetTrack AudioAssetTrack = Asset.TracksWithMediaType(AVMediaType.Audio)[0])
            {
                LayerInstruction.SetTransform(AudioAssetTrack.PreferredTransform, StartTime);
                AudioCompositionTrack.InsertTimeRange(TimeRange, AudioAssetTrack, StartTime, out InsertError);
            }
        }

        StartTime = CMTime.Add(StartTime, Asset.Duration);
        Counter++;
    }
}

AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction MainInstruction = new AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction
{
    TimeRange = VideoCompositionTrack.TimeRange,
    LayerInstructions = new AVVideoCompositionLayerInstruction[1] { LayerInstruction }
};

AVMutableVideoComposition CompositionInstruction = AVMutableVideoComposition.Create(Composition);
CompositionInstruction.Instructions = new AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction[1] { MainInstruction };
CompositionInstruction.FrameDuration = new CMTime(1, 30);
CompositionInstruction.RenderScale = 1.0f;
CompositionInstruction.RenderSize = FinalRenderSize;
string FilePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), FolderName, FileName);
await LocalStorage.DeleteFileAsync(FilePath);
NSUrl FilePathURL = NSUrl.CreateFileUrl(new string[] { FilePath });
MediaURL = FilePath;
AVAssetExportSession ExportSession = new AVAssetExportSession(Composition, AVAssetExportSessionPreset.Preset960x540);

if (CompositionInstruction != null)
{
    ExportSession.VideoComposition = CompositionInstruction;
}
ExportSession.ShouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true;
ExportSession.OutputUrl = FilePathURL;
ExportSession.OutputFileType = AVFileType.Mpeg4;

await ExportSession.ExportTaskAsync();
if (ExportSession.Status != AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Completed)
{
    throw new Exception(ExportSession.Error.DebugDescription);
}
```

Comment: What the format of your video?mp4 ,mov or some other?

Comment: Saving it as MPEG4

Comment: Updated code above.

Comment: Any help would be appreciated.